# Validation constraints do not trigger for registration form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I have a Doctrine user entity that I am trying to add form validators to for the registration form but they do not fire for the registration form under any condition.

My user entity:

```
namespace JMSHockey\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
 * My\AppBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Sorry, this email address is already in use.", groups={"registration"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="Sorry, this username is already taken.", groups={"registration"})
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface,\Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=75, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=75, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;

    ...
    }
```

Here's my UserType form:

```
namespace My\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email','email');
        $builder->add('username','text');
        ...
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'My\AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

And lastly, the registration form:

```
namespace My\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user', new UserType());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }
}
```

It seems like I must be missing something obvious here, but between the Symfony manual and the resources I've found online, I haven't been able to determine what it is.

Comment: Have you [enabled](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#configuration) annotations for validation?

Comment: Yes, I have `validation: { enable_annotations: true }` set in my config.yml under the framework section.

Comment: have you tried to specifically set cascade_validation on your RegistrationType?

Comment: I did this after you commented it -- didn't seem to have an affect though. I also realized this is affecting all constraints, not just the UniqueEntity constraints.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I resolved it by added `cascade_validation` at true in the `setDefaultOptions` method in your `RegistrationType` class and used the `OptionsResolverInterface` class from the OptionsResolver Symfony component:

```php
namespace My\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user', new UserType());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
         $resolver->setDefaults(array(
             'cascade_validation' => true
         ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find this groups option ?

You can left it blank so it will be triggered for this entity. If you want to specify an entity, it looks like you should use em option.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#em

Comment: The group option is so the constraints is relegated to the registration form only. I don't want the constraint to fire on every single update, or else the object would never be updatable without changing the e-mail address each time.

Comment: @Andy, this is wrong. The validation will not fail when you try to update the object without changing the email or username. This validation checks that this field is unique, ie that no other record has this value. When updating it will not check this against ITSELF, so it will be no problem. Have you tried removing the validation_group and groups options and see if it works?